# <list> of pointers to an object | Template argument is invalid

Tags: c++, list, templates, std

i´m new to C++ and programming in general. I have to write a program for my course in class "NAVI" which stores pointers to objects from type "Ort" (trans: Location) in a list. (The class "Navi" also has a few more functions, but ignore them). It HAS to be a list, even though a vector would make much more sense in my case.

The errors i get when compiling:

```
In file included from Ort.h:10:0,
                 from Ort.cpp:8:
NAVI.h:40:10: error: 'Ort' was not declared in this scope
list<Ort> *n;  
      ^
NAVI.h:40:13: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 list<Ort> *n;  
         ^
NAVI.h:40:13: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

My "Navi.h"  Header:

```
#ifndef NAVI_H
#define NAVI_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include "Ort.h"
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class NAVI {
public:
    NAVI();
    NAVI(const NAVI& orig);
    virtual ~NAVI();

    virtual void RouteBerechnen();

    void namenAnVektor(string n, int x);
    void namenAusVektorLoeschen(string st);
    void namenInDatei();
    void NamenEinlesen();
    void AlleAusgeben();
    void alleDatenBinaerSpeichern();
    void alleDatenBinaerLaden();
    void nachOrtSuchen(string start, string ziel);

private:


    list<Ort> *n;  
    const std::string binaerPfad = "C:\\Users\\Karsten\\Desktop\\Skripte u.     Unterlagen\\2. Semester\\PAD 2\\Praktikum\\binaerdaten.bin";
    const std::string dateiPfad = "C:\\Users\\Karsten\\Desktop\\Skripte u. Unterlagen\\2. Semester\\PAD 2\\Praktikum\\schreiben.txt";
};

#endif  /* NAVI_H */
```

My "Ort.h":

```
#ifndef ORT_H
#define ORT_H
#include "NAVI.h"

class Ort {
public:
    Ort(int cords,std::string n);
    Ort();
    Ort(const Ort& orig);
    virtual ~Ort();

    std::string getName();
    int getCords();
    void setCords(int cords);
    void setName(std::string n);

private:
    int GPSKoordinaten;
    std::string Ortsname;
};

#endif  /* ORT_H */
```

any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why does `Ort.h` include `Navi.h`?

Comment: You´re right, there´s no reason to include Ort.h in Navi.h - don´t know why I did that.  That also fixed my errors, but why? :)  And tyvm!

Answer (score 0):

The `#include` is almost like a copy/paste operation before the compiler gets to work on the file, and this means that even though `NAVI.h` was listed in an `#include` of `Ort.h`, its contents will not have been included by the time `Ort` is used.

If you include `Ort.h` in your program then the compiler will see the following:

```
#ifndef ORT_H
#define ORT_H
#include "NAVI.h" // ok, start with NAVI.h even though the compiler hasn't considered any of the rest of Ort.h yet
```

Which then becomes (some items irrelevant to this answer were removed):

```
#ifndef ORT_H
#define ORT_H
//#include "NAVI.h" // actual content of NAVI.h follows
#ifndef NAVI_H
#define NAVI_H
#include "Ort.h" // this is ignored, we already have #define ORT_H
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class NAVI {
public:
    NAVI();
    ...
private:
    list<Ort> *n;  // Compiler hasn't seen Ort yet
```

So, if you copy/paste the includes to *'see what the compiler sees'* you can understand why `Ort` was unknown.